# How can I show a file from my DB? 404 Error

Tags: php, laravel, file, http-status-code-404

I can't get a manual from my storage/app folder

My code

```
<td><a name="Manual" href="{{asset('storage/app').'/'.$machineData->getManual()}}">
                Manual de {{$machineData->getMachineName()}}</a></td>
```

Here I'm tryin' to show it "online"

On controller

```
protected function downloadFile($src)
{
    if(is_file($src))
    {
        $finfo=finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $content_type=finfo_file($finfo,$src);
        finfo_open($finfo);
        $file_name=basename($src).PHP_EOL;
        $size=filesize($src);
        header("Content-Type: $content_type");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: $size");
       
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public function download(Request $request)
{
    $note=$request->file('manual');
    if(!$this->downloadFile(app_path(). $note))
    {
        return redirect("/machineIndex");
       
    }

}
```

On this code I'm tryin' to download it, but it doesn't matter if it doesn't work. I just want to show the file, thanks!!

Comment: Is the storage link created? php artisan storage:link. Is the file in the public storage?

Comment: yes, I've created it

Comment: and the file is in the public storage?

Comment: the file is in storage/app/manual, is a new folder I've created

Comment: it needs to be in storage/app/public/manual to be available to open in the browser.